# Is it possible to create Fabry-Pérot Interferometer with one partially transparrent and one non-transparent mirror?

Tags: optics, interference, interferometry, displacement

In the literature sources I've found so far about Fabry-Pérot interferometer there are only example schematics of the interferometers in transmission - light source is placed from one side of the cavity and observer views fringe pattern from the other side of the cavity.

Let's consider the schematic of modified Fabry-Pérot interferometer with one non-transparent mirror:
[image: Modified Fabry-Pérot Interferometer with one non-transparent mirror]

What will happen to the observed interference pattern if one substitute one of the two partially transparent mirrors by the non-transparent mirror and observe fringes in reflection using beamsplitter?

I think the issue with such schematic may be that the light source is not point source, so the reflected and incident beams will not line up correctly to create interference pattern. There should some specific reason why all literature sources gives examples of extended light source for Fabry-Perot interferometer.

Comment: [Gires–Tournois Interferometers](https://www.rp-photonics.com/gires_tournois_interferometers.html)